# Find shorthest path between 2 nodes no more ideas

Tags: java

I have a graph represented as adjancy matrix and I want to find the shortest path between two nodes. The graph is weighted. I want to use BFS algorithm, I have tried but I ran out of ideas. Here is my code, if you could please help me .

```
public class A {
    private static int[][] adjacency = new int [4][4];
    static int n = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
                adjacency[i][j] = 0;    
        adjacency[0][1] = 2;
        adjacency[0][3] = 1;
        adjacency[1][0] = 2;
        adjacency[1][2] = 5;
        adjacency[2][1] = 5;
        adjacency[2][3] = 1;
        adjacency[2][4] = 2;
        adjacency[3][0] = 1;
        adjacency[3][2] = 1;
        adjacency[4][2] = 2;
    }

    public List<Integer> getNeighbors(int node, int[][] a) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            if (a[node][i] != 0)
                list.add(i);
        return list;
    }

    public List<Queue<Integer>> findPath(int start, int end, int[][] a) {
        List<Queue<Integer>> paths = new ArrayList<Queue<Integer>>();
        Queue<Integer> toVisit = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Queue<Integer> visited = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        toVisit.add(start);
        while(!toVisit.isEmpty()) {
              int node = toVisit.remove();
              visited.add(node);
              List<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
              neighbors = this.getNeighbors(node,a);
        }
          return paths;
    }
}
```

So basically what I was thinking was to find all the paths between the 2 given nodes, and store them in a list of queues, and then check which path has the shortest distance. Can you please help me.

Comment: BFS is a shortest path algorithm for equal weights across all links, are all your links the same weight?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem Did you read up there? I remember that Dijkstra and A* are pretty effective, albeit a bit inefficient.

Comment: @RB-Develop, I don't think they're considered "inefficient" for finding shortest paths. If you're comparing BFS to Dijkstra/A* then that isn't apples to apples.

Comment: @AlejandroLucena I may be wrong on that one then, I remember someone telling me they are not very fast. I still think they are a good approach though :)

Comment: I want to traverse the graph and store all paths found between the 2 given nodes and store them in a list, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: @user3421241 That approach is completely shying away from a BFS traversal.

Comment: I really don't understan. I admit this is homework and I'm required to use BFS. I asked the teacher to help me with some ideas and he said that is very simple. I just need to traverse the graph using BFS, store all the paths in a list and then check in the list which path has the shortest distance. That is what I am trying to do

Comment: That seems like a bit too much overhead. But a BFS-only approach wouldn't work since the edges are of different weights

Comment: What do you mean different wheights?

Comment: Can you help me please with this approach, I have no ideas how I could find all the paths between the 2 nodes

Answer (score 3):

There are several algorithms that can be used in your case. A very common approach is using Dijkstra's algorithm:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

A search for "Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm java" on google will give you several pages with examples on how to implement in Java.

Comment: Good answer, I think it would be helpful to mention in there that Dijkstra is a special case of the A* algorithm

Comment: I know that Dijkstra will be better but I have to use BFS. It is required

Comment: @user3421241 Dijkstra's is a type of BFS, also A* is a type of BFS.

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra's algorithm is ideal for your problem,
This URL is [Link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html)